# Best way to write this calculation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to write this calculation in Ruby?

```
amt = self.alt_inv - (self.alt_tax ? self.alt_tax : 0)
    - (self.alt_freight ? self.alt_freight : 0)
    - (self.misc1_amt ? self.misc1_amt : 0)
    - (self.misc2_amt ? self.misc2_amt : 0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby, if something is not nil, it will return true in a boolean expression and its value in a calculation.

I'm not explaining it really well, but you can do something like this:

```
amt = alt_inv - 
  (alt_tax     || 0) -
  (alt_freight || 0) -
  (misc1_amt   || 0) -
  (misc2_amt   || 0)
```

This is a more concise way of doing the ternary you were originally using.

---

Edit:

I actually like Jed Schneider's answer better than my own. I'll not copy it here, since his answer deserves the upvote for its elegance.

Answer (score 6):

Since `amt` is the difference between the sum of all the attributes and the `alt_inv`, you can sum the deductions and then subtract from `alt_inv`. `reduce` offers a clean way to do this. `compact` removes any `nil` values before performing the reduction.

Of course, attributes in this case can be expanded to whatever your needs are, even created dynamically from data, and in real life, I wouldn't use the variable attributes, obviously.

```
attributes = [alt_tax, alt_freight, misc1_amt, misc2amt]
amt = alt_inv - attributes.compact.reduce(:+)
```

reduce: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce

compact: http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/compact

Comment: I think that's needlessly complex.

Comment: IMHO four 'or' statements (or worse four ternary statements just to check nil) with four separate subtraction operators is needlessly complex

Comment: This is interesting from the code point of view, but I would NOT recommend this from the readability/maintenance point of view.

Comment: +1 This is by far the most readable, simplest, easiest and clearest solution. It's amazing what simplifications you can achieve even with just simple grade school level math! Of course, the *really correct* solution would *still* be to just fix the friggin' bug that leaks all those `nil` s into the domain model in the first place, but by now it seems obvious that the OP is simply unwilling to do that.

Comment: This solution scales better to lots of, or arbitrary sets of, deductions, but I would disagree with Jörg about its readability/simplicity. I agree 100% with Jörg about getting rid of the nils in the domain model, though.

Comment: @jorg I respect your opinion about the nils, but there are many instances when these domain models could see these values as nil, lets assume this is a Rails model and that tax is a float in the database, it is not set, it is nil, if you dont define it otherwise in the model.
@owen and @larry again assume it is a rails app and a product `:has_many` taxes, then with the `||` statements, you have to declare each tax specifically, check for nil and subtract. Add a new tax, then change the model code. It is far simpler and less fragile to call: `taxes.reduce(:+)`

Comment: Actually, I like @Jed Schneider's answer better than mine. Very elegant and terse. +1

Answer (score 5):

It might be cleaner if you could automatically initialize your object's values to 0 when the object was created, if those values were not supplied in the constructor. Otherwise, you need to do this sort of conditional logic everywhere in your objects these values are needed. Wouldn't you rather just do this?

```
amt = alt_inv - alt_tax - alt_freight - misc1_amt - misc2_amt
```

Comment: It may be that some of those fields are `nil` in cases where there was no freight/tax/etc

Comment: As Jörg notes below, the distinction between nil and 0 had then better be important enough to justify this extra complexity. I'm skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have local variable with same the name, instead of `self.alt_tax` you can write simply `alt_tax` without `self.`

Also the `||` operator returns the first operand when it's not nil otherwise it returns the second, so instead of:

```
alt_tax ? alt_tax : 0
```

you can write:

```
alt_tax || 0
```

Comment: A lot of Python programmers carry over this habit.  It makes code look so messy!

Answer (score 1):

A little variations from the solution of Jed, which is not needlessly complex, but more succinct IMHO.

Using `compact` and `inject` (the most common synonym of `reduce`) are not complex, and thoroughly used among Ruby programmers:

```
amt = [alt_tax, alt_freight, misc1_amt, misc2_amt].inject(alt_inv) do |result, attribute|
  result - (attribute || 0)
end
```

or:

```
amt = alt_inv - [alt_freight, misc1_amt, misc2_amt].compact.inject{|sum, n| sum + n }
```

which is an alternate way to write the `inject(&:+)` if you're uncomfortable with that syntax.
If you're using Rails, you can substitute the inject with the `sum` method, or [implement it yourself](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#M002396).

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me with two exceptions:

1) Ruby makes assumptions about statement endings.

Since

```
amt = self.alt_inv - (self.alt_tax ? self.alt_tax : 0)
```

is itself a valid statement, you need to either keep the minus on the prior line or escape the newline.

2) Ruby assumes "self" as the owner except for left side assignments. I suggest:

```
amt = alt_inv - 
  (alt_tax     ? alt_tax     : 0) -
  (alt_freight ? alt_freight : 0) -
  (misc1_amt   ? misc1_amt   : 0) -
  (misc2_amt   ? misc2_amt   : 0)
```

Comment: there is other way to write this condition. (alt_tax     ? alt_tax     : 0)

Comment: As others have said, you can also use the || operator's "short-circuit" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
amt = alt_inv - alt_tax.to_f - alt_freight.to_f - misc1_amt.to_f - misc2_amt.to_f
nil.to_f = 0.0
```